# Show Laptop Battery instead of Mouse Battery?

Tags: unity, mouse, power-management, indicator, battery

The battery status indicator in the top bar shows the mouse battery level instead of the laptop battery level. There does not appear to be any way to hide the mouse battery, or just make it so that it shows the laptop battery instead.

I'm currently using the battery indicator via indicator-sysmonitor, but the regular battery indicator would be much preferred.

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, I know that this is an old issue, and that there have been many bug reports and questions posted, but there does not seem to be a viable solution anywhere, at least not that I can find.
Are there still no solutions to this?

Comment: Under the Power settings, what is the "show battery  status in menu bar" set to?

Comment: @ubfan1 Right now it's set to Never, but the other two options make no difference. If I switch between them, the laptop battery might show up for a minute or two, but then it just switches back to the mouse.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not, but spoofing the mouse details to make it appear as a wired mouse would probably work.